# Highlight the table cells based on textbox value

Tags: jquery, html-table, textbox

I want to highlight the table cells having the similar value as textbox; i.e. as the user starts typing letters itself it should highlight the table cells....

```
<input type="text" id="txtsearch"/>  
<html>
<table id="table" style="height:350px;margin-left:1em;width:700px;">
    <!--this is my table header-->
    <tr style="display:table-row">
        <th class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox"/></th>
        <th class="Name">NAME</th>
        <th class="Score">SCORE</th>
        <th class="Email">EMAIL</th>
        <th class="Empty"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <!--tabledata-->
        <td ><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td >Vijay Prakash</td>
        <td >34</td>
        <td >vijay@gmail.com</td>
        <td ></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" id="btnCalculate" value="Calculate"/>
<label>Average:</label>
<label id="lblAverage"></label>
<label>Max:</label>
<label id="lblMax"></label>
</form>
</html>   
</div>
```

Comment: It shud highlight matching table cells

Comment: I have already tried and posted a different answer just see it...I am not getting the exact output what I wanted..datz the reasn I posted here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a case insensitive contains approach you could try the following:

```
    $("#text-box-id").keyup(function() {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        // you can add a class to the ones you want to be able to 
        // highlight and use like this
        $("td.highlightable").each(function(index, elem) {
            var $elem = $(elem);
            if (value.length > 0 && $elem.text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) != -1) {
                $elem.css('backgroundColor', 'yellow');   
            }
            else {
                $elem.css('backgroundColor', ''); 
            }
        });
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3leven11/s4tRu/2/

Comment: Actually on keyup its highlighting the cells when the cell contains that particular letter but..it should highlight only when it is going to be the first letter

Comment: Is der any way to highlight the cell even if the index is not -1 or zero...ie if the textbox value is "vijay" it should highlight the cell even if the cell contains "tttvijay"?

Comment: the code will already do that: http://jsfiddle.net/3leven11/s4tRu/3/ and type vijay into the text box

Answer (score 3):

use `keyup()` and `:contains`.

try this:

```
 $('#textBoxID').keyup(function(){
     $('td').css("background-color",''); 
     var value= $(this).val();
     $('td:contains("'+value+'")').css("background-color",'red');
 });
```

**updated**

I am creating a new method `containsIN` which works like jQuery contains and make it case insensitive:

```
 $.extend($.expr[":"], {
   "containsIN": function(elem, i, match, array) {
      return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || "").toLowerCase().indexOf((match[3] ||  "").toLowerCase()) >= 0;
    }
 });

  $('#textBoxID').keyup(function(){
      $('td').css("background-color",''); 
     var value= $(this).val();
     $('td:containsIN("'+value+'")').css("background-color",'red');
 });
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/K3aV6/3)

Comment: Should be `$('td:contains('+value+')')` instead of `$('td:contains(value)')`

Comment: Its not working..Its highlighting all the emailids but not the names...and not even the matching mailids its highlighting all cells of mailid column

Comment: updated.. fiddle here... http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/K3aV6/  ...contains is case s ensitive so if you type `V` it will highligt the names columns .. more example with multiple tr http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/K3aV6/1/

Comment: But its not working if the letters are of different case....It is not working for case sesitivity...ie If the textbox value is "vi" It shud highlight the cells which have "Vi" Or "VI" or even "vi"

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#SearchBox').on('keyup', function () {
                var textboxValue = $('#SearchBox').val();
                $('table td').each(function () {


                    if ($(this).text().indexOf(textboxValue) === 0) {
                        $(this).addClass('highlight');
                    } else {
                        $(this).addClass('t');
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: I am using the above code but dont know why its highlighting the emailid table cells...But not the table cells containg names..I want only the names to be highlighted..Is there any solution

Comment: see my answer for only highlighting specific cells